# How to extract a floating image from an excel sheet (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, xlsx, import-from-excel

I want to **extract** an image out of an **excel** sheet. Note the image is **not inside any of the cells** but rather **floats** on top of our cells. **`XLSX`** library **only extracts cell** information so that is not an option. Is there any other way using **`xlsx-extract`** or any other alternative. It may be possible on the server-side, but my question remains "Can it be done on the client-side?"

[image]

`xlsx` straight up can't pick it up.

I tried it using `xlsx-extract`, it can be used for Embedded Images but not for floating images outside a cell.

one approach was `aspose.cells` but it works on the server-side